# Does $\mathbb{Cov} \left(f(X),Y\right) = 0 \; \forall \; f(.)$ imply independence of $X$ and $Y$?

Tags: random-variable, independence

Does $\mathbb{Cov} \left(f(X),Y\right) = 0 \; \forall \; f(.)$ imply independence of $X$ and $Y$?

I am only familiar with the following definition of independence between $X$ and $Y$.

$$
f_{x,y}(x,y) = f_x(x)f_y(y)
$$

Comment: You need $\mathbb{Cov} \left(f(X),g(Y)\right) = 0  ~\text{for all (measurable)} ~f(\cdot), g(\cdot)$, not just $\mathbb{Cov} \left(f(X),Y\right) = 0 \; \forall \; f(\cdot)$

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Let's begin with the intuition.**  The slope of the ordinary least squares regression of $Y$ against $h(X)$, for any function $h$, is proportional to the covariance of $h(X)$ and $Y$.  The assumption is that *all* regressions are all zero (not just the linear ones).  If you imagine $(X,Y)$ represented by a point cloud (really, a probability density cloud), then no matter how you slice it vertically and reorder the slices (which carries out the mapping $h$), the regression remains zero.  This implies the conditional expectations of $Y$ (which are the regression function) are all constant.  We could screw around with the conditional *distributions* while keeping the expectations constant, thereby ruining any chance of independence.  We therefore should expect that **the conclusion does not always hold.**

**There are simple counterexamples.**  Consider a sample space of nine abstract elements $$\Omega = \{\omega_{i,j}\mid -1 \le i,j,\le 1\}$$ and a discrete measure with probability determined by

$$\mathbb{P}(\omega_{0,0})=0;\ \mathbb{P}(\omega_{0,j})=1/5\,(j=\pm 1);\ \mathbb{P}(\omega_{i,j}=1/10)\text{ otherwise.}$$

Define $$X(\omega_{i,j})=j,\ Y(\omega_{i,j})=i.$$

We could display these probabilities as an array

$$\pmatrix{1&2&1\\1&0&1\\1&2&1}$$

(with all entries multiplied by $1/10$) indexed in both directions by the values $-1,0,1$.

The marginal probabilities are $$f_X(-1)=f_X(1)=3/10;\, f_X(0)=4/10$$ and $$f_Y(-1)=f_Y(1)=4/10;\, f_Y(0)=2/10,$$ as computed by the column sums and row sums of the array, respectively.  Since $$f_X(0)f_Y(0)=(4/10)(2/10)\ne 0=\mathbb{P}(\omega_{0,0})=f_{XY}(0,0),$$ **these variables are not independent.**

This was constructed to make the conditional distribution of $Y$ when $X=0$ different from the other conditional distributions for $X=\pm 1$.  You can see this by comparing the middle column of the matrix to the other columns.  The symmetry in the $Y$ coordinates and in all the conditional probabilities immediately shows all conditional expectations are zero, whence **all covariances are zero,** no matter how the associated values of $X$ might be reassigned to the columns.

For those who might remain unconvinced, the counterexample may be demonstrated through direct computation--there are only $27$ functions that have to be considered and for each of them the covariance is zero.